# How to display Binary image in mpdf

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am saving image as binary to database. I want to display this image in MPDF. Normal image display is working properly but binary image can not displaying 
 The code I have used is
 
           `<td><img style="vertical-align: top" src="'.$studphoto.'" width="80" /></td>` 
The code I have used while inserting to database is

```
        $photo_get = file_get_contents($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]);
        list($width, $height, $image_type) = getimagesize($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]); /* Here gets image type */
        $mime_photo = image_type_to_mime_type($image_type); /* This function returns the mime type of the file when the image type got from getimagesize() is passed */
        $photo_en = base64_encode($photo_get);
        $photo = "data:" . $mime_photo . ";base64," . $photo_en;
```

The data getting from DB is 
`data:image/jpeg;base64,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` 
Please somebody help me to solve this :-(

Comment: How you are converting it to binary?

Comment: @Gautam3164 I have updated my question please check it..

Comment: I can display image in html using the code "<img style="vertical-align: top" src="'.$studphoto.'" width="80" />" but cant display in mpdf

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
<img src="<?php echo $studphoto;?>" />
```

And try to add the header with

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg;');
```

Comment: No `$studphoto` will be the binary data that you stored in DB

Comment: The data coming from db is data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsU.....

Comment: I just added the header

Comment: BTW did you give height and width for the images..?? ;-)

Comment: not mentioned width n height But displaying images for "<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
            /ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
            V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7" 
            width="16" height="14" alt="embedded folder icon">"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63777/discussion-between-salini-and-gautam3164).